# dynamically change a watch in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following watch in my controller.

```
var pageFunc = $scope.$watch('page["USER"].number', function(newob,oldob){
    console.log("WATCHING page");
    if(oldob != newob){
        //perform data load
    }
},true);
```

my collection looks like this

```
 page["USER"].number = 20;
 page["TESTER"].number = 60;
 page["BORROWER"].number = 30;
 page["CLIENT"].number = 80;
```

I need a single watch to watch all these collection changes for a particular element.

I have tried something like this.

```
       $scope.$watch('page[" '+$scope.selectedType+'"].number', function(newob,oldob)
```

where $scope.selectedType is set inside ng-init.

but since watch is triggered before ng-init, this fails. 
What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: If I watch page, it will trigger if any type is changed. 
eg - page["USER"] or page["CLIENT"]

what I need is at any given time to watch for a specific type of the collection only.

eg - watch $scope.$watch('page["CLIENT"].number')
  or       $scope.$watch('page["USER"].number')

Comment: and I can't hardcode them as separate watches because this collection can grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch its changes using a function callback:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return page[$scope.selectedType].number;
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if(oldValue != newValue) {
    // perform something
  }
});
```

Alternatively, if `$scope.selectedType` is a unique value, then I guess you can safely watch for it instead:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedType', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if(oldValue != newValue) {
    // perform something
  }
});
```